# $\sqrt{a^2+5b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+5c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+5a^2}\geq\sqrt{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8(ab+ac+bc)}$ for any real numbers.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, nested-radicals, uvw, buffalo-way

I think that this inequality is strong, though I do not have knowledge of many techniques. *There goes my work*:
Positive variables only make the inequality stronger, hence suppose $a,b,c\geqslant0$
$$
\sqrt{a^2+5b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+5c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+5a^2}\geqslant\sqrt{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8(ab+ac+bc)}
$$By squaring,
$$
\Rightarrow
\sqrt{(a^2+5b^2)(b^2+5c^2)}+\sqrt{(b^2+5c^2)(c^2+5a^2)}+\sqrt{(c^2+5a^2)(a^2+5b^2)}\geq2(a+b+c)^2
$$The $LHS$
$$=
\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}{5b^4 + 31a^2b^2 + 2\left(a^2 + 5b^2\right) \left(\sqrt{\left(b^2 + 5c^2\right) \left(c^2 + 5a^2\right)}\right)}}
$$$$
\geqslant 
\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}{5b^4 + 31a^2b^2 + 2(a^2 + 5b^2)(bc + 5ca)}}
$$
Now we are only left to prove that
$$
\sum_{cyc}{5b^4 + 31a^2b^2 + 52a^2bc + 10a^3c + 10a^3c} \geqslant \sum_{cyc}{4a^4 + 16(a^3b + ab^3) + 24a^2b^2 + 48a^2bc}
$$$$
\sum_{cyc}{a^4 + 7a^2b^2 + 4a^2bc - 6(a^3b + ab^3)} \geqslant 0
$$
The last inequality is wrong for $(a,b,c) = (1,1,0)$. Cauchy Schwarz looks fine but I am not able to find a way.
I found this inequality posted by arqady on aops forum.
Please help!

Comment: Say me please, who is the author of this inequality?

Comment: AM-GM in 2nd step for LHS gives the result $6(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge 2(a+b+c)^2$, which is easily provable to be true.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg You have founded it.

Comment: And @AniruddhaDeb You are loosening the inequality, by applying AM-GM there. So it is not proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  where is your inequality written? I bought the first Cirtoaje book, you have some entries there.

Comment: @WillJagy This inequality is from one of his posts on AoPS site.

Comment: And  @Michael Rozenberg, I apologize if I have done something bad to you, but don't you have a proof of this inequality?

Comment: @Will Jagy I created it yesterday. See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2290905p18034221

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg In that case I would say it should not be posted here so soon. it is rude to do so. The foreword to the book indicates AoPS as a primary source, with Vasc as Cirtoaje's username. I am not positive, it would appear your user name there is arqady  or possibly Nguyenhuyen. The first one, you did put your name in the little profile page.

Comment: @Will Jagy My username in AoPS it's arqady. I don't see any problem to post this inequality here. By the way, in this site there are very many my inequalities without any link that it's mine.. What can I do with it? This is our life, apparently... :)

Comment: @BookOfFlames well this is a very strict inequality. And by the way, your last "wrong" inequality could be written as $(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)(a^2+b^2+c^2-5(ab+bc+ca)) \geq 0$. I don't know if that can help us see anything?

Comment: @ĐàoMinhDũng That leaves us with $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 \geqslant 5(ab + bc + ca)$. It is wrong, but still, I think that following my approach and squaring again will give more strict result. But I have another estimation for this inequality: $\sum_{cyc}{(a^2 + 5b^2)\sqrt{\left(b^2 + 5c^2\right)\left(c^2 + 5a^2\right)}}\geqslant\frac{ \left(\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt{a^2 + 5b^2}}\right)^2}{\sum_{cyc}{\frac{1}{a^2 + 5b^2}}}$, still I am not sure it will help.

Comment: Use rational bounds for $\sqrt{a^2+5b^2}$, then Buffalo Way works. But it is a computer solution (very very complicated by hand).

Comment: @RiverLi What do you mean by rational bounds?

Comment: @River Li  I also got that it's enough to prove an inequality with one radical and little coefficients, but by another idea.  In the rest I still don't see a human proof.

Comment: @BookOfFlames  Please see my previous answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997333/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-sqrt3a24bc-geq-sqrt345abacbc/3303551#3303551, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036890/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-sqrta210bc-geq-frac12-sum-limits-cyc-sqr/3372011#3372011

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg A fun thing I noticed. Iff $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and If instead of 8, it was k while $$k \in [-8,8]$$ the inequality holds true, anything other than that (even if k is < -8), the inequality is false for some a,b,c

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi That means the inequality is very strict; It will not be obliterated by usual means.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  Often, if we eliminate the square root signs in some inequalities, the resulting polynomial inequalities are complicated and hard to prove by hand.

Comment: I think one can WLOG consider the case $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, due to homogeneity. I ran simulations on a very dense unit sphere in MATLAB and it appears to hold, but this of course is a dirty way to prove it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Also, for a weak one, $\sqrt{a^2+5b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+5c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+5a^2}\ge 3\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2 + ab + bc + ca}$, there is a nice solution by hand.

Comment: @River Li  $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+5b^2}\geq\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{cyc}(28a^2+26ab)}$ also has a nice proof, but it's stronger. See my post.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Nice. I used something similar, that is $a^2 + 5b^2 = \frac{(a+5b)^2}{6} + \frac{5}{6}(a-b)^2$; and C-S to get $\sqrt{a^2+5b^2}\sqrt{b^2+5c^2} \ge \frac{1}{6}(a+5b)(b+5c) + \frac{5}{6}(b-a)(b-c)$.

Comment: @River Li Yes, it's nice and it helps to remove three radicals in the starting inequality. We need now to remove the last radical. I got that  $\sqrt{\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)}{6}}\geq\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3b+5b^3c+15a^2b^2+15a^2bc)}{6(a+b+c)}.$ and it's enough to prove that: $\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)+\frac{2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3b+5a^3c+15a^2b^2+15a^2bc)\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(14a^2+13ab)}}{3(a+b+c)}\geq4(a+b+c)^4.$ I can not check, if it's true. But if it's true, I can prove it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Please check $\sqrt{\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)}{6}}\geq\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3b+5b^3c+15a^2b^2+15a^2bc)}{6(a+b+c)}$ for $a=2, b=1, c=0$?

Comment: @River Li   I made a typo. Change $b^3c$ on $a^3c$ as in the second inequality.  If the second inequality is true, it would be beautiful! Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  Please check the second inequality for $c = 0, b=1, a=6$?

Comment: Yes I see. Thank you! Now I see that I could  find it by myself. Id est, we still have no a nice proof. :(

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  You may also notice the identity $a^2 + kb^2 = \frac{(a+kb)^2}{k+1} + \frac{k}{k+1}(a-b)^2$.
Also we have $\sqrt{a^2 + kb^2} = \frac{a+kb}{\sqrt{k+1}} 
+ \frac{\frac{k}{k+1}(a-b)^2}{\sqrt{a^2 + kb^2} + \frac{a+kb}{\sqrt{k+1}}}$
from which we can obtain some bounds.
I used it for $k=3$ inequality.

Comment: @River Li  $k=5$, you mean. Yes, of course. We can get it by C-S. See my post.  But it does not so help. The second is interesting.

Comment: When $k=3$, it is $\sqrt{a^2 + 3b^2} = \frac{a+3b}{2} + \frac{3(a-b)^2/4}{\sqrt{a^2+3b^2} + (a+3b)/2}$. For both $k=3, 5$, by good bounds, there is a computer solution. I can not prove it by hand.

Comment: I have found the effective approach, but too late.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov you still have 27 mins

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Maybe I'm not able to provide you with the bounty amount but you can post your answer at least.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x\leq|x|$, it's enough to prove our inequality for non-negative variables.

Now, after squaring of the both sides we need to prove that $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2+5b^2)(b^2+5c^2)}\geq2(a+b+c)^2.$$
Also,
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2+5b^2)(b^2+5c^2)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left((a^2+5b^2)(b^2+5c^2)+2(c^2+5a^2)\sqrt{(a^2+5b^2)(b^2+5c^2)}\right)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(5a^4+31a^2b^2+2\sqrt{\prod_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)}\sqrt{a^2+5b^2}\right)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)+2\sqrt{\prod_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)}\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(6a^2+2\sqrt{(a^2+5b^2)(b^2+5c^2)}\right)}}.$$
But by C-S
$$2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2+5b^2)(b^2+5c^2)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{((a+5b)^2+5(a-b)^2)((b+5c)^2+5(b-c)^2)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}((a+5b)(b+5c)+5(b-a)(b-c)).$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)+2\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\prod_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)\sum_{cyc}(28a^2+26ab)}\geq4(a+b+c)^4$$ or
$$2\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\prod_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)\sum_{cyc}(28a^2+26ab)}\geq4(a+b+c)^4-\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2),$$ which is obvious for $$4(a+b+c)^4-\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)<0.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove our inequality for $$4(a+b+c)^4-\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)\geq0.$$
Now, let $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+u$ and $c=a+v$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$8\prod_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)\sum_{cyc}(14a^2+13ab)\geq3\left(4(a+b+c)^4-\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)\right)^2,$$ for which it's enough to prove that:
$$8\prod_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)\sum_{cyc}(14a^2+13ab)-3\left(4(a+b+c)^4-\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)\right)^2\geq$$
$$\geq4\left(u^2-5uv+v^2\right)^2\left(4(a+b+c)^4-\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)\right ).$$
Now, $$8\prod_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)\sum_{cyc}(14a^2+13ab)-3\left(4(a+b+c)^4-\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)\right)^2=$$
$$=19008(u^2-uv+v^2)a^6+5184(4u^3-5u^2v+15uv^2+4v^3)a^5+$$
$$+144(109u^4-458u^3v+867u^2v^2+742uv^3+109v^4)a^4+$$
$$+64(114u^5-677u^4v+529u^3v^2+2399u^2v^3+1088uv^4+114v^5)a^3+$$
$$+4(438u^6-2978u^5v+107u^4v^2+13656u^3v^3+20467u^2v^4+5822uv^5+438v^6)a^2+$$
$$+4(42u^7-269u^6v-191u^5v^2+2403u^4v^3+5523u^3v^4+5249u^2v^5+851uv^6+42v^7)a-$$
$$-3u^8+96u^7v-250u^6v^2+1288u^5v^3+1671u^4v^4+3368u^3v^5+1990u^2v^6+96uv^7-3v^8.$$
Also, $$4(a+b+c)^4-\sum_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)=$$
$$=216a^4+288(u+v)a^3+4(31u^2+77uv+31v^2)a^2+$$
$$+(28u^3+82u^2v+82uv^2+28v^3)a-u^4+16u^3v-7u^2v^2+16uv^3-v^4.$$
Easy to see that $$19008(u^2-uv+v^2)\geq19008uv,$$
$$5184(4u^3-5u^2v+15uv^2+4v^3)\geq80899\sqrt{u^3v^3},$$
$$144(109u^4-458u^3v+867u^2v^2+742uv^3+109v^4)-$$
$$-4\left(u^2-5uv+v^2\right)^2\cdot216\geq99373u^2v^2,$$
$$64(114u^5-677u^4v+529u^3v^2+2399u^2v^3+1088uv^4+114v^5)-$$
$$-4\left(u^2-5uv+v^2\right)^2\cdot288(u+v)\geq35586\sqrt{u^5v^5},$$
$$4(438u^6-2978u^5v+107u^4v^2+13656u^3v^3+20467u^2v^4+5822uv^5+438v^6)-$$
$$-4\left(u^2-5uv+v^2\right)^2\cdot4(31u^2+77uv+31v^2)\geq-6165u^3v^3,$$
$$4(42u^7-269u^6v-191u^5v^2+2403u^4v^3+5523u^3v^4+5249u^2v^5+851uv^6+42v^7)-$$
$$-4\left(u^2-5uv+v^2\right)^2\cdot(28u^3+82u^2v+82uv^2+28v^3)\geq11491\sqrt{u^7v^7}$$ and
$$-3u^8+96u^7v-250u^6v^2+1288u^5v^3+1671u^4v^4+3368u^3v^5+1990u^2v^6+96uv^7-3v^8-$$
$$-4\left(u^2-5uv+v^2\right)^2(-u^4+16u^3v-7u^2v^2+16uv^3-v^4)\geq5432u^4v^4.$$
Now, let $a=\sqrt{uv}t.$

Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$19008t^6+80899t^5+99373t^4+35586t^3-6165t^2+11491t+5432\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore  $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)(b^2+5c^2)=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b^2+5a^2b^2+5a^4+25a^2b^2)=\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2).$ I hope now it's clear.

Comment: Though I have not checked, maybe assuming constraints due to homogeneity work to some extent?

Comment: Maybe... If. It leads to the proof, so why not?

Comment: I know that this in a way stupid: But how did you invent it without having the proof of this inequality?

Comment: @Book Of Flames I proved it, but by very ugly way and with helping of WA. Try to prove $\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a^4+31a^2b^2)+2\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2+5b^2)\sum\limits_{cyc}(28a^2+26ab)}\geq4(a+b+c)^4.$ I think it's very perspective.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  It is ingenious to introduce $\cdots \geq4\left(u^2-5uv+v^2\right)^2\cdots$. (+1)

Comment: @River Li  Thank you! But this idea does not help for the following inequality. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857856

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the proof you are looking for, but a proof nonetheless.

The inequality is really sharp, and I don't think that a manual solution exists. Concretely, I don't think that one can find a lower bound on the LHS, such that we can algebraically confirm that it upper bounds the RHS. However, it is easy to numerically verify that the inequality holds, and I hope that you can find this convincing.

Specifically, divide both sides by $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$, then we're left with the equivalent inequality:
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + 5y^2} + \sqrt{y^2 + 5z^2} + \sqrt{z^2 + 5x^2} \geq \sqrt{10 + 8(xy + yz + xz)},
$$
where $x = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}, y = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}, z = \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$, and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Furthermore, it has been established that we can safely assume that $x,y,z\geq 0$, so it is sufficient to verify the inequality on the surface $\{(x,y,z) \in\mathbb{R}^3 ~\vert~ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1, x,y,z\geq 0\}$, which can be parameterized with $$x = \sin\theta\sin\omega,\quad y = \sin\theta\cos\omega,\quad z=\cos\theta,$$ with $(\theta,\omega)\in[0,\pi/2]\times[0,\pi/2]$.

Now, if one minimizes the function
$$
h(\theta,\omega) = \sqrt{x^2 + 5y^2} + \sqrt{y^2 + 5z^2} + \sqrt{z^2 + 5x^2} - \sqrt{10 + 8(xy + yz + xz)},
$$
over the square $[0,\pi/2]\times[0,\pi/2]$, one then finds that it has a unique global minimum 0 at $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, or at $\theta \approx 0.9554,~ \omega = \pi/4$, see the figure below which shows the level sets of $h$.

[[image: Level sets of <span class=]$h(\theta,\omega)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNYar.png)

This implies by homogeneity that the original inequality is equality only at $a=b=c$, and a strict inequality at all other values.

Comment: How do you prove the unique minimization of $h(\theta,\omega)$ at the point you claim? The proof is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of proof :

We show the hardest case when $a\geq b\geq c $ and $5a^2+c^2\geq 5b^2+a^2\geq 5c^2+b^2$

If we show the following statement :

Let $a\geq b\geq c>0 $ and $5a^2+c^2\geq 5b^2+a^2\geq 5c^2+b^2$ and $n\geq 400$ a natural number then we have :

$$\frac{1}{n+1}(5a^2+c^2)+\frac{n}{n+1}\Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big)\geq \frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\quad(1)$$

And :

$$\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}(5a^2+c^2)+\frac{n}{n+1}\Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big)\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}(5b^2+a^2)+\frac{n}{n+1}\Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big)\Big)\geq \Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big)^2\quad(2)$$

And :

$$\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}(5c^2+b^2)+\frac{n}{n+1}\Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big)\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}(5a^2+c^2)+\frac{n}{n+1}\Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big)\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}(5b^2+a^2)+\frac{n}{n+1}\Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big)\Big)\geq \Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big)^3\quad(3)$$

And then applying Karamata's inequality we show :

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n+1}(5a^2+c^2)+\frac{n}{n+1}\Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big)\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n+1}(5b^2+a^2)+\frac{n}{n+1}\Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big) \frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n+1}(5c^2+b^2)+\frac{n}{n+1}\Big(\frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}\Big) \frac{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)-8(ab+bc+ca)}{9}}\geqslant\sqrt{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8(ab+ac+bc)}
\quad(4)$$

Remains to apply this kind of inequality :

$$\sqrt{x}\frac{1}{k+1}+\sqrt{y}\frac{k}{k+1}\geq \sqrt{x\frac{1}{n+1}+y\frac{n}{n+1}}\quad (5)$$

Where $x,y>0$ and $n,k>0$ naturals numbers .

Applying $(4)$ to $(5)$ we get the desired inequality .

$(1)$ is trivial we prove $(2)$ now :

Due to homogeneity we put $a=1+p+q$ , $b=1+p$, $c=1$ and now we use WA .

See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%285%281%2Bp%2Bq%29%C2%B2%2B1%29%2F400%2B%2810%281%2Bp%2Bq%2B1%2Bp%2B1%29%C2%B2-12%28%281%2B1%2Bp%2Bq%29%281%2Bp%29%2B1%2Bp%2Bq%29%29*399%2F%28400*9%29%29%28%285%281%2Bp%29%C2%B2%2B%281%2Bp%2Bq%29%C2%B2%29%2F400%2B%2810%281%2Bp%2Bq%2B1%2Bp%2B1%29%C2%B2-12%28%281%2B1%2Bp%2Bq%29%281%2Bp%29%2B1%2Bp%2Bq%29%29*399%2F%28400*9%29%29) for the LHS and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810%281%2Bp%2Bq%2B1%2Bp%2B1%29%C2%B2-12%28%281%2B1%2Bp%2Bq%29%281%2Bp%29%2B1%2Bp%2Bq%29%29%C2%B2%2F81) for the RHS of $(2)$ . If we substract each coefficient the remainders is positive wich prove the inequality $(2)$ .We can show $(3)$ by a similar way .

Hope you learn something from me and it helps you .

Regards Max

Comment: Say please, how your post helps to prove the starting inequality?

Comment: Please check (2) for $a=1, b=1, c = \frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg let the time to edit .

Comment: @RiverLi it's partial but it works for some others values . Thanks to checks it ! I keep this in mind .

Comment: @ErikSatie  So you need to make more assumptions besides $a\geq b\geq c$ and $\frac{a}{c}\geq\frac{b}{a}\geq \frac{c}{b}$ and $b\geq a\frac{(b+c)}{(a+b)}$.

Comment: @RiverLi can you confirm there is no mistakes in the last inequality that I cannot prove ?Thanks !!

Comment: @ErikSatie The last inequality does not hold.

Comment: @RiverLi And now ?

Comment: @ErikSatie $\sqrt{5(a+c)^2+(b+c)^2}+\sqrt{a^2+5b^2}\geq \sqrt{10(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8(ab+bc+ca)}$ does not hold, given that $a \ge c \ge b > 0$, $a/b \ge c/a \ge b/c$. For example, $a=3472, b = 3056, c = 3471$.

Comment: @RiverLi look better my answer  because if we have $b=x$ , $c=x+y$ , $a=x+y+z$ I add the condition $x\leq z$ or $b+c\leq a$

Comment: @ErikSatie  Can you give the complete condition for your partial answer in the first line of your answer?

Comment: @RiverLi I add something else , if it's true enjoy it !

Comment: @ErikSatie  I think that you should improve your writing which is not good for me to read.

Comment: @RiverLi I do my best hope you see clear now !

Comment: @ErikSatie  I think that it is not good to add constraints in the proof (for example, "Wich is true because we add the constraints" ). You should put complete constraints in the statement then you prove the statement. By the way, why you begin with initial capitals, for example, "Wich is true because we add the constraints :" should it be "which is true..."?

Comment: @RiverLi no problem I have not the time now but I shall correct it .Thanks!!

Comment: @ErikSatie  Also, you never use period.

Comment: @RiverLi I admit that I cannot prove it without a computer and Karamata's inequality . Sorry for the waste of time .Regards Max.

Comment: @ErikSatie  It is nice to discuss inequalities with you. This inequality is not easy by hand.